# Cannot disable metadata_csum from buildroot configuration

Tags: linux, ext4, u-boot, buildroot, file-metadata

I'm trying to boot STM32MP157A-DK1 with a Buildroot image that I made but I got this error and I cannot disable the `metadata_cesum` from the Buildroot configuration.

I tried

```
BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_EXT2_MKFS_OPTIONS="-O ^64bit,^metadata_csum,^dir_index"
```

to disable it but with no results.

[image: Screenshot of output]

Comment: It would be better to [edit] and include the output as text, because a screenshot is not "text searchable".

Answer (score 0):

The environment that you have seems does not understand `metadata_csum`. You may try to manually disable in PC environment with

```
tune2fs -O metadata_csum
```